# How to enable "ttlAfterFinished=true" in the kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

After trying all possible configurations I ask here if anyone knows how to enable `ttlAfterFinished=true`?

I use the K8S version 1.17.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable it via the **feature gate** in kube controller manager and kube API Server. If Kube controller manager and kube API Server is deployed as static pod then you can find the deployment yaml at

`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`

and

`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

in the **master** node.

Edit both manifests files and add this line at the bottom of the command section:

```
- --feature-gates=TTLAfterFinished=true
```

After the yaml is edited and saved, the kube controller manager and the kube API Server pod will be **automatically** recreated with this feature enabled.

You can verify by checking logs of kube controller manager pod and you should see below

```
I0308 06:04:43.886097       1 ttlafterfinished_controller.go:105] Starting TTL after finished controller
```

Tip: you can specify multiple feature gates using comma, for example:

```
--feature-gates=TTLAfterFinished=true,OtherFeature=true
```

Comment: Note for GKE users: TTLAfterFinished seems to be enabled on alpha clusters.

Comment: It works for Kubespray managed clusters. Just did it on a running system. To make sure Kubespray is in sync `kube_feature_gates` or `kubeadm_feature_gates` variable should be set too - https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/vars.md